# How to convert this particular json string into a python dictionary?

Tags: python, json

How do I convert this string ->

```
 string = [{"name":"sam"}]
```

into a python dictionary like so ->

```
data = {
         "name" : "sam"
       }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
In [1]: import json

In [2]: json.loads('[{"name":"sam"}]')
Out[2]: [{u'name': u'sam'}]
```

This returns a list, the first element of which is the desired dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

```
string = [{ "name" : "sam" }]
data = string[0]
```

now the data is the dict

Comment: Further, even if you had a string that contained a valid Python expression, you'd have to `eval` it to get the corresponding object, which raises a number of security issues.