# problems getting data from FlightRadar24 with urllib2

Tags: python, json, url

I'm trying to get data from FlightRadar24 using the script below, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/526695/3904031) to handle cookies. When I currently type that url into a browser, I get a nice long json or dictionary including a list of lat/long/alt updates. But when I try the code below, I get the error message listed below.

What do I need to do to successfully read the json into python?

**NOTE**: that link may stop working in a week or two - they don't make the data available forever.

```
import urllib2 
import cookielib

jar = cookielib.FileCookieJar("cookies")
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(jar))
url = "http://lhr.data.fr24.com/_external/planedata_json.1.3.php?f=72c5ef5"

response = opener.open(url)
print response.headers
print "Got page"
print "Currently have %d cookies" % len(jar)
print jar
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[mypath]/test v00.py", line 8, in 
    response = opener.open(link)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 448, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what you need cookies for, but the issue is that the webserver is blocking access to the user-agent being sent by urllib in the request header (which is something like - `'Python-urllib/2.7'` or so) .

You should add a valid browser User-agent to the header to get the correct data. Example -

```
import urllib2
url = "http://lhr.data.fr24.com/_external/planedata_json.1.3.php?f=72c5ef5"
req = urllib2.Request(url, headers={"Connection":"keep-alive", "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
jsondata = response.read()
```

Comment: Great! This works, thank you very much! Time to read about user-agents. I added the cookie handling when my first attempts resulted in messages complaining that cookies weren't enabled. I wonder if the User-Agent here is just automatically accepting cookies.

Comment: I do not think so, you may have did something else as well which caused that error, not sure.

Comment: That's quite possible. Thanks for the quick response @AnandSKumar!

Answer (score 2):

The first [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32163003/3904031) by @AnandSKumar is the accepted answer but here are a few more lines that are helpful, since the `jsondata = response.read()` returns a string.

**NOTE**: that link may stop working in a week or two - they don't make the data available forever.

```
import urllib2
import json
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# FROM this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32163003
# and THIS ANSWER: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32163003/3904031
# and a little from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6826511

url        = "http://lhr.data.fr24.com/_external/planedata_json.1.3.php?f=72c5ef5"

req        = urllib2.Request(url, headers={"Connection":"keep-alive", "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})

response   = urllib2.urlopen(req)

the_dict   = json.loads(response.read())

trail      = the_dict['trail']

trailarray = np.array(trail)


s0, s1 = len(trailarray)/3, 3

lat, lon, alt = trailarray[:s0*s1].reshape(s0,s1).T

alt *= 10.  # they drop the last zero


# plot raw data of the trail. Note there are gaps - no time information here

plt.figure()

plt.subplot(2,2,1)

plt.plot(lat)
plt.hold
plt.plot(lon)
plt.title('raw lat lon')

plt.subplot(2,2,3)
plt.plot(alt)
plt.title('raw alt')

plt.subplot(1,2,2)
plt.plot(lon, lat)
plt.title('raw lat vs lon')
plt.text(-40, 46, "this segment is")
plt.text(-40, 45.5, "transatlantic")
plt.text(-40, 45, "gap in data")

plt.savefig('raw lat lon alt')
plt.show()
```

To convert the time and date info to human form:

```
def humanize(seconds_since_epoch):
    """ from https://stackoverflow.com/a/15953715/3904031 """
    return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(seconds_since_epoch).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

import datetime
humanize(the_dict['arrival'])
```

returns

```
'2015-08-20 17:43:50'
```

[image: raw lat lon alt]