# How do I convert this string into a dict in python?

Tags: python, json, string, csv

I have a string that I get from a mongodb export into a csv:  Here's an example:

```
[{"group":"Most Common","id":"00000000000002","name":"HVAC Specialists","name_singular":"HVAC Specialist"},{"group":"Other","id":"00000000001","name":"Hauling \u0026 Junk Removers","name_singular":"Hauling \u0026 Junk Remover"}]
```

I'm trying to put the date into a dict so I can pull out what I need and export it.

I tried putting in into a list, but it created elements out of each letter.

The string is in a txt file and I'm calling it like this:

```
python stringwork.py thestring.txt
```

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826495/how-to-convert-this-particular-json-string-into-a-python-dictionary) and tried this:

```
from sys import argv
import json

# filename = argv

txt = open(argv[1])

json.loads(str(txt))
```

And I got the following error.

```
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Is what you are reading from `argv[1]` the line of text you provided in your question?

Comment: I copied your string and used a `json.loads` call, and it worked fine. I'm not sure what your exact input to your script is, but based on what you provided, I can't really replicate.

Comment: I tried with this string, there is no problem. Maybe your input `argv` wrong?

Comment: what is with the down vote?  cmon guys.  i'm trying to learn here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `txt` variable is a file object and can't be converted to a string. So you should read the contents of the file object such as `txt = open(argv[1]).readlines()`. Then you can obtain the string in the `txt` list with `txt[0]`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from sys import argv
import json

filename = argv

txt = open(argv[1]).readlines()

a = json.loads(str(txt[0]))
print(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are a bit confused here:

```
txt = open(argv[1])
json.loads(str(txt))
```

After this, `txt` is a file object, not the actual string.

For that you'll need to do something like this:

```
txt = open(argv[1]).read()
json.loads(txt)
```

Here `txt` is already a string with the file content, so there is no need for `str`.

Do check the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/inputoutput.html) on reading / writing files.